# django migrate from CIEmailField to collation

Tags: django, collation

I did upgrade django version to 4.2.8 and then the CIEmailField() is deprecated.

I used this CIEmailField on the email field of an user. So I had to change to:

```
email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_collation="case_insensitive")
```

So the migration is like this:

```
operations = [
        CreateCollation(
            "case_insensitive",
            provider="icu",
            locale="und-u-ks-level2",
            deterministic=True,
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name="user",
            name="email",
            field=models.EmailField(db_collation="case_insensitive", max_length=254),
        ),
    ]
```

But before this changement, with CIEmailField I would .get() an user with this email "test@test.com" or "TEST@test.com".

With the case_insensitive collation I made it work only by setting "deterministic=False". But with that, the SQL's LIKE is not working. So every Viewset with "email" in "search_fields" wont work.

To make it work, I only found this solution:

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    search_fields = ("email_deterministic", ...)

    ...

    def get_queryset(self, request: HttpRequest) -> QuerySet[User]:
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(request)
            .annotate(
                email_deterministic=Collate("email", "und-x-icu"),
            )
        )
```

So I have to do that EVERYWHERE on the App when I have an user to search by his email. But the App is big.

Is there any other solution for this?